# php file upload not working in mac

Tags: php, macos, file-upload

Simple php file upload example is not working in mac. Being an java developer hard to check errors with scrpting languages

```
<html>
<head>
<title>File Upload Form</title>
</head>
<body>
This form allows you to upload a file to the server.<br>

<form action="getfile.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post"><br>
Type (or select) Filename: <input type="file" name="uploadFile">
<input type="submit" value="Upload File">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

and getfile.php as

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Process Uploaded File</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php

move_uploaded_file ($_FILES['uploadFile'] ['tmp_name'],
       "uploads/{$_FILES['uploadFile'] ['name']}")

?>
</body>
</html>
```

I have looked into google for acl issues or php.ini setting for file size everything looks ok to me
regarding acl gave 777 permission to document directory
regarding php.ini setting checked the file upload sizes params and its using 50M 
and file tried was 100kb image file

Can anyone help me out on setting up this on mac?

Comment: Try enabling error reporting `error_reporting(E_ALL)` or use a try catch to get the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to put the whole path in the "to" field of the move_uploaded_file. And see if it works, if it works, that is probably caused due to the fact that the uploads directory (when using relative path) is a different one that you think it is.

Comment: it worked but releative path should also work right ?

Comment: It should, but you must think that the "uploaded" directory you have there might point to somewhere else other than the one you expected.

So, in order for the relative path to work, you should find where is the "uploaded" folder and then grant 777 access (or so) to it.

Answer (score 3):

Check that particular uploaded folder permissions.
and change it to all user as '***Read & Write***'

Comment: While this may resolve the problem granting rw access to all users is generally a bad idea